# I uninstalled Trebuchet from nexus5 using lucky patcher

Tags: nexus-5

Help please I uninstalled Trebuchet from nexus5(thinking it was a bad app ) using lucky patcher  now it wont boot.  Please help me guys!!

Comment: It shouldn't stop booting entirely, just show a black screen instead. USB debugging on? `adb install` a new launcher from your PC.

Comment: Yea your right. Just a black screen. Yes USB debugging is on.  How do I install the new launcher on my laptop? It has a Ubuntu system on it

Comment: Install Android SDK first (so that you have the `adb` binary), then `adb install /path/to/file.apk` to sideload the APK to be installed. I have little experience with Ubuntu so I won't risk offering you details, but shouldn't be hard. Here's some link for reference: [installing ADB](http://lifehacker.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-androids-adb-and-fastboot-to-1586992378); [using ADB install](http://adbshell.com/commands/adb-install)

Comment: Hi Andy. The phone is so screwed up now :( I should have tried to follow your instructions but instead   my bf insisted he take the phone to a phone fix store called Nano TECH and they had it for 2 hours,  costed 55$,  came home, turned it on..  ...  and Oh my gawwwd its worse then ever.  just a black screen with white Google in the middle of the screen and a white lock emoji on the bottom for 5 seconds and then it vibrates and goes blank then the same thing again. . No Kali. No Twrp Manager..  Wow

Comment: Dang. Try flashing a factory image? I hope you can still enter fastboot mode...

Answer (score 0):

From this state you just need to enter fastboot mode and reflash Lineage (or whatever custom ROM you're using) the same way you flashed it initially.